# Javascript, calcular millisegundos hasta fecha fija

Tags: javascript, html, calculo

tengo que hacer un ejercicio de javascript. En este ejercicio necesito que se muestre mediante una ventana emergente un mensaje que diga la fecha y hora actuales pero, además, tengo que poner los milisegundos que quedan para acabar el año. La parte de la fecha y hora es sencilla y ya la he acabado, ¿cómo puedo hacer la segunda parte?

Este es mi código (perdón si no he escrito bien el código, es la primera vez que uso esta página).

```
    var f = new Date();
            
    var msg = "La fecha de hoy es: "+(f.getDate() + "/" + (f.getMonth() +1) + "/" + f.getFullYear() +" y son las: "+f.getHours() +" horas con "+ f.getMinutes() + " minutos y "+f.getSeconds() + " segundos.");
        alert(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo, basta restar los milisegundos actuales (cantidad de milisegundos transcurridos desde el 01 de Enero de 1970) y los milisegundos al 01 de Enero del año siguiente (en este caso 2023), a las 00:00 horas.

Para obtener los milisegundos transcurridos desde el 01 de Enero de 1970 ([Tiempo Unix o Unix Epoch](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix)), puedes usar el método [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) del objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Por ejemplo:

```js
const fechaActual = new Date();
const milisegundosActual = fechaActual.valueOf();
```

Eso te da la cantidad de milisegundos transcurridos desde el 01 de Enero de 1970 hasta la fecha actual.

Si deseas la cantidad de milisegundos transcurridos hasta el 01 de Enero de 2023 a las 00:00 horas, lo podrías usar así:

```js
const fechaNewYear = new Date(2023,0,1);
const milisegundosNewYear = fechaNewYear.valueOf();
```

Se observa que he usado directamente el valor de año, mes y día. Hay que tomar en cuenta que si no se pasan los valores correspondientes al tiempo, se establecen todos a 0, además, los meses se contabilizan empezando desde 0, por lo que a Enero le corresponde 0, a Febrero 1 y así sucesivamente.

Ahora solo falta restar la cantidad de milisegundos, tomando en cuenta que el mayor será el de año nuevo. Por lo tanto:

```js
const fechaActual = new Date();
const milisegundosFechaActual = fechaActual.valueOf();
const fechaNewYear = new Date(2023,0,1);
const milisegundosNewYear = fechaNewYear.valueOf();

alert(`Hoy es: ${fechaActual} y faltan ${milisegundosNewYear - milisegundosFechaActual} milisgundos para año nuevo`);
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: muchas gracias, Mauricio. Un saludo.

Comment: Si la respuesta es válida, [puedes marcarla como tal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Eso te da puntos y mantiene la visibilidad de tu pregunta y la respuesta o respuestas. Saludos